# Parallel Job Consumer

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net

Edit: [A second iteration of this problem here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32073/parallel-job-consumer-using-tpl)

I need to provide a service (either a Windows Service or an Azure Worker Role) which will handle the parallel execution of jobs.  These jobs could be anything from importing data to compiling of reports, or to sending out mass notifications, etc.  They are generally long-running and are not suitable to run on the web server.

**Important factors**

- The solution needs to be a very extensible and maintainable solution, as new job implementations will be created by developers all the time.
- The execution of these jobs is to be abstracted away from the client code.  All developers need to do is to create the new job and add it to the job data source (database, MSMQ, Azure Queue, etc).

**Solution**

Deriving from `AbstractJob` and overriding the abstract `Execute()` method to provide implementation for the new job:

```
public abstract class AbstractJob
{
    public JobState State { get; protected set; }

    public AbstractJob()
    {
        State = JobState.New;
    }

    protected abstract bool Execute();

    public sealed void ExecuteJob()
    {
        State = JobState.Executing;

        try
        {
            if (Execute())
            {
                State = JobState.Successful;
            }
            else
            {
                State = JobState.Failed;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            State = JobState.FailedOnException;
        }
    }
}

public class TestJob : AbstractJob
{
    protected override bool Execute()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Test job!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The following `JobConsumer` would reside on a Windows Service or Azure Worker Role.  `IJobSource` provides the consumer with jobs.  These could be from the database, a MSMQ, an Azure Queue, etc (I have left this implementation out).

Every 5 seconds (this can obviously be configurable), the `JobConsumer` executes new jobs when there are available cores.

```
public class JobConsumer
{
    public List<AbstractJob> Jobs { get; set; }

    public IJobSource JobSource { get; private set; }

    public int ParallelExecutionCount { get; set; }

    protected List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public JobConsumer(IJobSource jobSource, int parallelExecutionCount)
    {
        JobSource = jobSource;
        ParallelExecutionCount = parallelExecutionCount;
    }

    public void StartConsumer()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            TaskScheduler currentScheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;

            while (true)
            {
                int availableCores = ParallelExecutionCount - Tasks.Count();

                IEnumerable<AbstractJob> newJobs = 
                    JobSource.ReadNewJobs().Take(availableCores);

                foreach (var job in newJobs)
                {
                    System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = null;

                    task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        Tasks.Add(task);
                    }, CancellationToken.None, 
                       TaskCreationOptions.None, 
                       currentScheduler)
                    .ContinueWith(t => 
                    {
                        // Execute job on a new thread
                        job.ExecuteJob();
                    })
                    .ContinueWith(t => 
                    {
                        Tasks.Remove(task);
                    }, currentScheduler);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface IJobSource
{
    public IEnumerable<AbstractJob> ReadNewJobs();
}
```

Input, critique and suggestions very welcome!

**EDIT:**  I am using .NET 4.5

Comment: I wrote similar code polling a serial port and used the same looping methods you've used. Except I added a timeout error count, which would reset every time it connected successfully. I don't know if you want to count your job errors, to create some system flag??

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Wouldn't it actually be easier to convert the `Execute` to `ExecuteAsync` returning a `Task` and the `AbstractJob` to `IJob`? `Task` carries everything that you put in the `JobState` flag and more (e.g. if it failed, why). Then you could also drop the task creation on consumer side and use either `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or `BlockingCollection<T>` to process the jobs, but that depends on .NET version.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek I think that unless explicitly mentioned, you can safely assume at least .Net 4.0.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5 - Sorry for not stipulating.

Comment: @Patryk:  Thanks for your comment!  The `ExecuteAsync` idea sounds much better.  But the reason why I decided on an abstract class is because I am concerned that I may want to include certain properties (like a `SendNotificationOnComplete` flag or `Priority` setting).  A priority field would also mean that I couldn't use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` if I understand correctly.  Feel free to formulate an answer :)

Comment: @davenewza Depending on how your `Priority` is supposed to work, you might be able to implement it using multiple `ConcurrentQueue`s (or, more likely, multiple `BlockingCollection`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The way you're using `TaskScheduler.Current` to try to synchronize access to `Tasks` won't work (unless this code runs under a very specific custom `TaskScheduler`).

   With the default scheduler, a `Task` can be executed on any `ThreadPool` thread, which means that multiple threads could access `Tasks` at the same time. The simplest fix for that is to use `lock` instead of trying to use `TaskScheduler` (which will also simplify your code a bit).

   Since you seem to be using `Tasks` just for counting, another option would be to replace it with `int` field and then use `Interlocked.Increment()`/`Decrement()` to modify it.
2. I think you should save the exception that's caught in `ExecuteJob()` somewhere, so that when you encounter an issue, you can actually diagnose it.

   Also, it looks like you're not saving the results of jobs anywhere. I think that's a bad idea, you should have some sort of logging, to see where the problem was when something doesn't work right. (Was the job even scheduled? Did it complete successfully? Etc.)

   And I'm not sure you want to differentiate between "failed" and "failed on exception". When something fails, you usually want to know *why* it failed, which is what exceptions are for.
3. Why are most of the properties of `JobConsumer` public? If you want to allow adding a new job to `Jobs`, but nothing else, then create a method for that.

   And why is `Tasks` protected, when you don't have any virtual methods? The default accessibility should be private (which means you don't need a property anymore and you can use just a field) and you should change that only when you have good reason.
4. The way you use `ReadNewJobs()` seems to indicate that items are actually consumed only when the enumerable is iterated. That's not a bad idea (`BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()` does the same thing), but it should be documented *very clearly* that that's what is expected from the method.
5. Since you're on .Net 4.5, you can use `await Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`. This means you would need to make the lambda `async` and you should probably also use `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` (which is a good idea anyway, because it's shorter).
6. There is no need to spell the name `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` in full, use just `Task`.
7. I don't think that the name `AbstractJob` needs to emphasize that the class is abstract, calling it just `Job` would work just as well. Another possible name is `JobBase`.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply.  You have made some really helpful point.  I have a question. Would you use an abstract `Job` class or an `IJob` interface for implementation of new jobs?  I feel that an `IJob` is the more correct choice, but I really want the job to have a `JobState`.

Comment: @davenewza You could always do both. But I think that abstract class makes more sense here, because of `ExecuteJob()` (if you used an interface, each implementation would have to repeat the code for that method).

Comment: I have created a second iteration of the above code (and have implemented a lot of your comments).  Your feedback/review would be awesome:  [post here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32073/parallel-job-consumer-using-tpl).