# Parallel Job Consumer using TPL

Tags: c#, design-patterns, serialization

I need to provide a service (either a Windows Service or an Azure Worker Role) which will handle the parallel execution of jobs. These jobs could be anything from importing data to compiling of reports, or to sending out mass notifications, etc.

**Database Design:**

The whole process of running these jobs is persistent.

[image]

- `JobDefinition` stores varchar reference to the `IJob` concrete type class.
- `JobInstance` is an instance of `JobDefinition` which needs to be executed as a job.
- `JobInstanceEvent` stores the process of executing an instance (the change of states).

**Class Structure:**

[image]

In order to create new jobs the simple `IJob` interface needs to be implemented:

```
public interface IJob
{
    bool Execute();
}
```

`JobHandler` is responsible for deserializing the serialized varchar in the database and also saving state changes:

```
public class JobHandler
{
    public string State 
    {
        get
        {
            return jobInstance.State;
        }
        set
        {
            using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
            {
                context.JobInstances.Attach(jobInstance);
                jobInstance.State = value;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            SaveJobEvent(String.Empty);
        }
    }

    private JobInstance jobInstance;

    public JobHandler(JobInstance job)
    {
        jobInstance = job;
    }

    public IJob CreateJobObject()
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(jobInstance.JobDefinition.FullAssemblyType);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(jobInstance.SerialisedObject))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as IJob;
        }
    }

    public void SaveJobEvent(string jobEventMessage)
    {
        using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
        {
            context.JobInstances.Attach(jobInstance);

            jobInstance.JobInstanceEvents.Add(
                new JobInstanceEvent() 
                { 
                    State = jobInstance.State,
                    Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Message = jobEventMessage
                }
            );

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The `JobConsumer` is what will run in the service.  It performs two primary parallel tasks:

- Adding items to the blocking queue (through polling)
- Executing items from the blocking queue (through thread blocking)

It is able to run multiple jobs concurrently (`ParallelExecutionSlots`).

```
public class JobConsumer
{
    public IJobSource JobSource { get; private set; }

    public BlockingCollection<JobHandler> JobQueue { get; private set; }

    public int ParallelExecutionSlots { get; private set; }

    private bool isPopulating;

    private CancellationTokenSource consumerCancellationTokenSource;

    public JobConsumer(IJobSource jobSource, int parallelExecutionSlots)
    {
        JobQueue = new BlockingCollection<JobHandler>();

        JobSource = jobSource;

        ParallelExecutionSlots = parallelExecutionSlots;
        consumerCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        StartPopulatingQueue();
    }

    public void StartPopulatingQueue()
    {
        StartPopulatingQueue(500);
    }

    public void StartPopulatingQueue(int pollingDelay)
    {
        if (!isPopulating)
        {
            isPopulating = true;

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (isPopulating)
                {
                    foreach (var job in JobSource.ReadNewJobs())
                    {
                        job.State = "Queued";

                        JobQueue.Add(job);
                    }

                    Tasks.Task.Delay(pollingDelay).Wait();
                }
            })
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                isPopulating = false;
                JobConsumerLog.LogException("JobConsumer populating process failed", t.Exception);
            },
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
                TaskScheduler.Current
            );
        }
    }

    public void StopPopulatingQueue()
    {
        isPopulating = false;
    }

    public void StartConsumer()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            SemaphoreSlim slotsSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(ParallelExecutionSlots);

            foreach (var job in JobQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable(consumerCancellationTokenSource.Token))
            {
                slotsSemaphore.Wait();

                JobHandler jobHandler = job;

                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ExecuteJob(jobHandler);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        slotsSemaphore.Release();
                    }
                },
                    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
                );
            }

            consumerCancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        }, consumerCancellationTokenSource.Token)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            JobConsumerLog.LogException("JobConsumer execution process failed", t.Exception);
        },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
            TaskScheduler.Current
        )
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            JobConsumerLog.LogException("JobConsumer execution process stopped", t.Exception);
        },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled,
            TaskScheduler.Current
        );
    }

    public void StopConsumer()
    {
        consumerCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void ExecuteJob(JobHandler job)
    {
        job.State = "Executing";

        try
        {
            if (job.CreateJobObject().Execute())
            {
                job.State = "Successful";
            }
            else
            {
                job.State = "Failed";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            job.State = "FailedOnException";
        }
    }
}
```

Feedback on the overall design would be much appreciated.  I'm looking for a  **maintainable and extensible solution**.

I am using .NET 4.5

(Note: this is a second iteration of the [following post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31903/parallel-job-consumer))

Comment: I think you don't have ReSharper installed and screaming at your private field naming convention! Prefixing them with an underscore really helps readability I find - I was WTF-looking for a local variable when I came across `jobInstance`. Declaring them at the top of the class also helps, especially if you're not prefixing them and you're using them before they're declared. Call that a "readability review" :) Is `JobConsumerLog` a static class? I'd just replace that with a constructor-injected `ILogger`, otherwise you've got *ambient context* here, not obvious the thing is logging anything.

Comment: Have you considered Quartz.NET, it contains a lot of job running logic out of the box and also retry policies etc. It is more of an scheduling framework but in your case you could it set it to run jobs as fast as possible (fire now).

Comment: You might want to look into using something like Microsoft HPC if you aren't set on rolling your own solution, as that seems to be what you need.

Comment: Have you consider using Windows Workflow Foundation (WFF) for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only some few minor things:

1. In `StartPopulatingQueue` to me as the reader it's unclear in what unit `pollingDelay` is in. Two classic solutions:

   - Change it to be a `TimeSpan` - I usually prefer this since it provides the most flexibility.
   - Add the unit suffix to the parameter name. like `Ms` for milliseconds or `Sec` for seconds etc.
2. `CreateJobObject` can potentially return `null` if the deserialized object cannot be cast to `IJob` in which case `ExecuteJob` will throw a `NullReferenceException` which is typically not very meaningful. You should throw a more meaningful exception on deserialization (as mentioned in the comment by Roman you could use a direct cast instead of `as` which would throw an `InvalidCastException`)
3. It feels wrong to me that the consumer defines the job execution states. The consumer seems largely responsible for managing the job queue and it should stick to that single responsibility. Hence I think `Execute` should be moved into `JobHandler`.
4. I'd also consider moving `CreateJobObject` to `JobInstance` so `JobInstance` is responsible to provide the actual object instance. Then `JobHandler` is just concerned with the state changes of the job.

Comment: Adding to your second point: This should be a direct cast rather than "as".